# Long jQuery Ajax request goes in loop at server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have ajax request that does duplication work at server side (PHP).
For small amount of duplication units, it works perfectly fine.
I get proper response server and the request ends gracefully

But when the doing the same request for 1500 units, the request goes on and on in firebug.
At sever side, when it has completed replication of 1500 units, the function is called somehow and the entire process begins again.
I am using simple MVC framework at PHP side.

Thanks.

Comment: would be helpful to see an example of the code you're executing.  Also, what is 'the function' that is called somehow? If you're seeing a repeating process, and you're using jQuery to perform the AJAX request, check into your event handler (`.on('click'`) etc) to ensure the handler itself isn't attached multiple times. You can ensure this with `.off('click').on('click', function(){})`

Comment: we show a pop up when user initiates process and close it once the process is completed,

Comment: if there had been issues, even the small amount of duplication would have resulted in over duplication